# How can I align and space these form input fields horizontally, given the context (Bootstrap 4)?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If I apply `justify-content:center` to the row in which the form sits, it stays on top of New Task. Also, there is an `+` button after the last `input` field:

```html
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<div id="addTaskFieldsDiv">
  <div id="new-task">
    <h6>New task</h6>
  </div>
  <form id="form">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap  justify-content:center">
      <div style="width: 30%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="taskList" placeholder="Pick a task">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="review and approve on page recommendations">Review and approve on page recommendations</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 12%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-2"><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
      <div style="width: 10%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-2"><input type="link" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste a link"></div>
      <div style="width: 30%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></div>
      <div style="width: 12%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-2"><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
      <div style="width: 5%" class="form-group col-sm col-md-1"><button id="addTask" type="submit" onclick="addTaskToDb()">+</button></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</html>
```

This is what it should look like, but with less space in between the fields.
[image]

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.onit-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }


        .form-group:first-child {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        .form-group {
            flex: auto;
            margin: 0 5px;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"/>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="addTaskFieldsDiv">
        <div id="new-task">
          <h6>New task</h6>
        </div>
        <form id="form">
          <div class="onit-row">
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 30%;">
              <select class="form-control" id="taskList" placeholder="Pick a task">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="review and approve on page recommendations">Review and approve on page recommendations</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 12%;"><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 10%;"><input type="link" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste a link"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 30%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 12%;"><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: fit-content;">
            <button id="addTask" type="submit" onclick="addTaskToDb()" style="width: 100%;">+</button></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```